# AttributeError when trying to access StringVar from another class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I've been working on a Personal Training App in python I have a Start Up window, referenced in the code as StartUp. Once the user enters the name of the client that they want to see records for, I'm trying to get the name variable from the StartUp class to the Application class. However, when I run it, it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/home/ninja65/PtApp/main.py", line 32, in <lambda>
old = tk.Button(mainframe, text='Open', command=lambda:[parent.destroy(), Workspace()],bg='sienna3')
File "/home/ninja65/PtApp/main.py", line 16, in Workspace
App = Application(root)
File "/home/ninja65/PtApp/main.py", line 55, in __init__
self.target = StartUp.target
AttributeError: type object 'StartUp' has no attribute 'target'
```

the Code is below

```
# !usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import json

def CreateNew():
  temp = tk.Tk()
  temp.title('Enter New Client')
  New = MakeNew(temp)
  temp.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
  temp.mainloop()

def Workspace():
  root = tk.Tk()
  root.config(bg='grey9')
  root.title("Personal Trainer")
  App = Application(root)
  root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
  root.mainloop()

class StartUp():
  def __init__(self, parent):    
    mainframe = tk.Frame(parent, bg='firebrick4')
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N)
    # Adding widgets to the frame
    opening = tk.Label(mainframe, text='Welcome, what do you want to do?', font='tahoma', bg='firebrick4', fg='khaki3')
    guide = tk.Label(mainframe, text="Type the Client's name with no gaps", font='tahoma', bg='firebrick4', fg='khaki3')
    guide.grid(columnspan=10, row=1)
    opening.grid(columnspan=10, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
    self.target = tk.StringVar()
    open_entry = tk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable=self.target)
    open_entry.grid(columnspan=7, row=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, padx=5)
    old = tk.Button(mainframe, text='Open', command=lambda:[parent.destroy(), Workspace()], bg='sienna3')
    old.grid(column=7, columnspan=4, row=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, pady=5, padx=5)
    new = tk.Button(mainframe, text='New Client', command=lambda:[parent.destroy(), CreateNew()], bg='sienna3', font='tahoma')
    new.grid(columnspan=10, row=3, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, pady=5, padx=5)


class MakeNew:

def __init__(self, loader):
    menubutton = tk.Menubutton(loader, text = "File")
    menubutton.grid()
    menubutton.menu = tk.Menu(menubutton)
    menubutton["menu"]=menubutton.menu
    menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "New file")
    menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "Save")
    menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "Save as")
    menubutton.pack()

def method(self):
    pass

class Application(StartUp):
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.target = StartUp.target
    menubutton = tk.Menubutton(master, text = "File",font='gothic', bg='#86C232')
    menubutton.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    menubutton.menu = tk.Menu(menubutton, bg='#86C232')
    menubutton["menu"]=menubutton.menu
    menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "New file")
    menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "Save")
    menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label = "Save as")
    # Frame of vital info
    v_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg='gray16')
    v_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    # Frame of Additional info
    a_frame = tk.Frame(v_frame)
    a_frame.grid(column=5, row=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N)
    # Frame of Exercise routine
    e_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg='grey18')
    e_frame.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.S)
    # First Row of Vital Info
    cl_name = tk.Label(v_frame, text=self.target, bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    cl_age = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Age', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    cl_height = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Height', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    cl_weight = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Weight', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    cl_sex = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Gender', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=4, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    # Second Row of Vital Info
    cl_bfp = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Fat %', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    cl_lbm = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Lean Mass', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    cl_gw = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Goal Weight', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    cl_bmi = tk.Label(v_frame, text='BMI', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    # Last Row
    cl_goal = tk.Label(v_frame, text='Goals that the client put go here', bg='gray15', fg='#61892F',font='tahoma').grid(columnspan=5, row=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    # Additional Column
    atest = tk.Label(a_frame, text='Test', bg='gray22').grid(column=0, row=0)
    # Exercise Routine Column
    mday_label = tk.Label(e_frame, text='Monday', bg='gray18', fg='#61892F', font='gothic').grid(column=0, row=0)
    tday_label = tk.Label(e_frame, text='Tuesday', bg='gray18', fg='#61892F', font='gothic').grid(column=1, row=0)
    wday_label = tk.Label(e_frame, text='Wednesday', bg='gray18', fg='#61892F', font='gothic').grid(column=2, row=0)
    thday_label = tk.Label(e_frame, text='Thursday', bg='gray18', fg='#61892F', font='gothic').grid(column=3, row=0)
    fday_label = tk.Label(e_frame, text='Friday', bg='gray18', fg='#61892F', font='gothic').grid(column=4, row=0)
    saday_label = tk.Label(e_frame, text='Saturday', bg='gray18', fg='#61892F', font='gothic').grid(column=5, row=0)
    sday_label = tk.Label(e_frame, text='Sunday', bg='gray18', fg='#61892F', font='gothic').grid(column=6, row=0)
    mday = tk.Listbox(e_frame, bg='gray22').grid(column=0, row=1)
    tday = tk.Listbox(e_frame, bg='gray22').grid(column=1, row=1)
    wday = tk.Listbox(e_frame, bg='gray22').grid(column=2, row=1)
    thday = tk.Listbox(e_frame, bg='gray22').grid(column=3, row=1)
    fday = tk.Listbox(e_frame, bg='gray22').grid(column=4, row=1)
    stday = tk.Listbox(e_frame, bg='gray22').grid(column=5, row=1)
    sday = tk.Listbox(e_frame, bg='gray22').grid(column=6, row=1)

def method(self):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  sub = tk.Tk()
  sub.config(bg='firebrick4')
  sub.title('PT App Login')
  Window = StartUp(sub)
  sub.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
  sub.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to ask yourself when (and if) you define `Startup.target` and when you try to use `Startup.target`.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  I'm not quite sure I follow. I define StartUp.target in the __init__ method and in the Application class i reference that. I've tried defining 'target' as a Startup class attribute, but then that raises a tkinter error.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  After a session of staring at the screen, I decided to merge the classes and have Application run as a method in StartUp. That way it'll inherit everything just fine. Saves me some headache too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two problems. For one, you are trying to reference `Startup.target`, which is a reference to a *class* variable. You haven't defined a class variable named `target`. You have instead defined an *instance* variable named target.

Also, your `Application` inherits from `Startup` but it does not call the `__init__` method of `Startup` so the object is incorrectly initialized. Since `Application` inherits from `Startup`, it should be initialized like this:

```
class Application(StartUp):
  def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    ...
```

Once you do that, there's no reason to do `self.target = Startup.target` since `self.target` already exists.

There are other bugs in the code, but this explains the error your question is asking about and how to fix that specific error.

Comment: Yeah, I made a little bit of a mess there. I rearranged it and merged the classes and the project is finished and working. Thanks for your input!